# After installing macOS Catalina or later on a APFS drive, is there a way of removing the system and revert back to one partition only?

Tags: catalina, big-sur, apfs

I needed a fresh install to perform some tests, so I installed Big Sur on a secondary SSD. I don't need the dual partition setup any more, so I would like to revert the state of the APFS column to one partition only. Is this possible without a complete backup ? Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question and include the output from the command `diskutil list`. –

Comment: I'm seconding this request - you shouldn't get additional partitions when you install Big Sur - `diskutil list` would help clarify what you're referring to